# Fastest 3D format for import of large files

Tags: import

I often need to import large/detailed scenes to Blender and luckily I can choose the 3D format for it. There are no animations or any other advanced features involved, just a lot of polygons and a few materials. I noticed that some 3D format importers are implemented via Python (like obj is currently rewritten to C++ at [GSoC](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/gsoc-2020-faster-io-for-obj-stl-ply-feedback/13528)), but some should be already implemented in native C++ ... no idea which ones.

So I am wondering **what is currently the fastest 3D format to import large geometry?**

The answer to a related question [Import large model file into Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10588/import-large-model-file-into-blender) seems outdated and the cited Blender docs page does not exist anymore.